# How to trim trailing characters (not whitespace) from a string?

Tags: regex, string, sed, cut

How could you go about trimming an n number of characters from the end of a string?

Strings of interest in column 2:

```
1 022102201212021
2 201212210221021
3 021201122012210
4 201212101120002
```

Trimmed strings with last 5 characters removed:

```
1 0221022012
2 2012122102
3 0212011220
4 2012121011
```

Would like to be able to trim any arbitrary number of characters off of the end of the string in column 2. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the column to trim is the last column:

```
awk '{print substr($0, 0, length-5)}' < INPUT > OUTPUT
```

If there might be more columns after the column to trim:

```
awk '{$2 = substr($2, 0, length($2)-5); print}' < INPUT > OUTPUT
```

Answer (score 1):

Using sed:

```
sed 's/.\{5\}$//' file
1 0221022012
2 2012122102
3 0212011220
4 2012121011
```

Using awk you can do this to strip last 5 characters from each of the line:

```
awk -F '.{5}$' '{print $1}' file
1 0221022012
2 2012122102
3 0212011220
4 2012121011
```